# Encountered this error when calculating the accuracy on a test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, training-data

I am new to Machine learning, and I have this error to calculate and return the accuracy on a test data

```
def NBAccuracy(features_train, labels_train, features_test, labels_test):
    """ compute the accuracy of your Naive Bayes classifier """
    ### import the sklearn module for GaussianNB
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

    ### create classifier
    clf = GaussianNB() #TODO

    ### fit the classifier on the training features and labels
    clf.fit(features_train, labels_train, features_test, labels_test) #TODO

    ### use the trained classifier to predict labels for the test features
    pred = clf.predict(features_test, labels_test) #TODO

    ### calculate and return the accuracy on the test data
    ### this is slightly different than the example, 
    ### where we just print the accuracy
    ### you might need to import an sklearn module
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
    accuracy = accuracy_score(features_test, labels_test, normalize=False) #TODO
    return accuracy
    return NBAccuracy
```

I got this error:

> TypeError: fit() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)

Comment: You pass to many arguments to your fit Method. fit(X, y, sample_weight=None) Are all possbile arguments. You should read the docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.fit

Comment: Fit does not take the test features or labels, only the training ones.

Answer (score 1):

You have train data and test data but you cannot use test data also in training and predict output on the same data.

```
 clf.fit(features_train, labels_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10)
```

Batch size and epochs can be varied based on your training dataset

And accuracy should be calculated between your prediction output and original output

Answer (score 1):

These areas need to be corrected:

(1) need 2 parameters to fit, and they are training data to train the model, which are `features_train` and `labels_train`

(2) prediction is done on test data, ie, `features_test`

(3) accuracy is done by comparing the truth `labels_test` and the prediction `pred`

(4) only 1 return statement is needed, and do return a variable `return accuracy` (not the function `return NBAccuracy`)

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
    
def NBAccuracy(features_train, labels_train, features_test, labels_test):
    """ compute the accuracy of your Naive Bayes classifier """
    clf = GaussianNB()
    clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
    pred = clf.predict(features_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(labels_test, pred, normalize=False)
    return accuracy
```

Answer (score 0):

def NBAccuracy(features_train, labels_train, features_test, labels_test):
""" compute the accuracy of your Naive Bayes classifier """
### import the sklearn module for GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

```
### create classifier
clf = GaussianNB()#TODO

### fit the classifier on the training features and labels
#TODO
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)

### use the trained classifier to predict labels for the test features
pred = clf.predict( features_test) 
# print(labels_test)


### calculate and return the accuracy on the test data
### this is slightly different than the example, 
### where we just print the accuracy
### you might need to import an sklearn module
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy = clf.score(features_test, labels_test) #TODO
return accuracy
```